# Why does Tailwind not display the proper bg color when starting a development server?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am currently using ReactJS(TypeScript) with TailwindCSS to create some forms, and I want my Submit button to use one of the yellow colors that come with Tailwind. However, when I have my react project running and I update the value to bg-yellow-300 , it will turn yellow, but when I first launch the react app, the button has its default color scheme, which I don't want. I've provided the code for the button below, and my config file:

```
<Button className="w-1/12 bg-yellow-300 hover:bg-yellow-400 text-black-100" type="submit">
            Submit
</Button>
```

Config File:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 'node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "gold":"#edcd37",
        "babyblue":"#298ge5",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
}
```

I've tried adding the JIT(Just in time) setting to see if for some reason that was why it wasn't giving the correct color on initial loading, but it didn't work either.

Comment: If you're using the latest tailwind version, "jit" is unnecessary since it already integrated into tailwind. Maybe you could try going through the documentation again and see if you've installed everything correctly

Comment: I just double checked that everything was installed correctly, and everything seems to be in order.